# Cloud Function example on Google docs onCreate not triggering

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently extremely confused as to why the below code is not running properly. I am following the exact steps from: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started and I just can't get the second cloud function makeUpperCase to trigger. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const original = req.query.text;
    const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({ original: original });
    res.json({ result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.` });
});


exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{documentId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const original = snap.data().original;
    functions.logger.log('Uppercasing', context.params.documentId, original);
    const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();

    return snap.ref.set({ uppercase }, { merge: true });
});
```

Comment: Since can't see what you're doing, it's not possible for us to say what you might be doing wrong.  Please edit the question to explain the full set of steps that you take that should trigger the function.  Please include the step where you deploy the function, and the result of the deploy.

Comment: thanks for replying! I am not sure why but after but everything seemed to work only after I subscribed and deployed it! do you have any idea why onCreate ran only after I subscribed and deployed and the other function just seemed to work without subscribing and deploying?

Comment: You simply have to deploy the code.  It's a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You have to deploy Cloud Functions code before it gets triggered.  The triggers are only going to work against actual database data when running in Google Cloud.  Simply writing the code locally isn't going to work, and the local emulators will not work either.  In order to get actual changes from actual document data in Firestore, the code must be deployed.